# IzPack - A dynamic variable needs either a value attribute or a value element

Tags: izpack

I have a problem when I try to build IzPack installer from my install.xml file. It says > com.izforge.izpack.compiler.CompilerException: null:A dynamic variable needs either a value attribute or a value element. Variable name: RegistryReadTest

This code was copied from site https://izpack.atlassian.net/wiki/display/IZPACK/Dynamic+Variables

I am using IzPack from gradle plugin com.bmuschko:gradle-izpack-plugin:2.1
I've heard it is independent project, could it be that this doesn't support this type?

```html
<dynamicvariables>
    <variable name="RegistryReadTest" checkonce="true"
              regkey="HKLM\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager\\Environment"
              regvalue="Path"/>
</dynamicvariables>
```